# sqlite- interlinking two database tables using foreign keys

Tags: sqlite

In SQL in general, but in SQLite for this case, can we establish a foreign key from one table say, `table` in `db1.db` to `mainTable` in `db2.db`. That is we can use a foreign key relationship in `table` by referencing the primary key in `mainTable`, the main idea being to use this relationship to trigger `ON DELETE CASCADE`. (Briefly in my case, `mainTable` happens to be a system maintained SQLITE database, which I'd like to avoid manual finding and analyzing. If I could somehow access establish this key, life would be a lot easier).